# critical points and linearization of non linear systems help with correcting mistakes

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

need help with assignment. i have attempted the question best i can. please help correct my mistakes if there are any?

$x' = x^2 y - x y$
$y' = y - e^x$

(a) find all critical points of the system
ans >>> (0, 1) & (1, e)

(b) for critical points not on the y-axis
(i) find the corresponding lininearization of the system with the critical point translated to (0,0)
 **no idea what the translation meant**

ans >>> no idea how to make a matrix so makeshift matrix

|X'| = | e 0| |X|
|Y'| = |-e 0| |Y|

(ii) using eigenvalues and eigenvectors, find the general solution to the linearized system in (i).
ans >>> value1 = e vector1= |1-e| | e |
        value2 = 1 vector2= | 0 | |e-1|
       GS= c1( vector1) e^et + c2( vector2) e^t
***extra question*** how do i determine which eigenvector to pick when one eigenvalue has 2 eigenvectors?

Comment: hey, no. i edited the post. how do i make my equation look like yours?

Comment: and do you know how to make a matrix?

Comment: MathJax, put a $\$$ in beginning and end. See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For the translation, see: http://users.etown.edu/h/hughesjr/ma321/notes/c6s2.html

Comment: so are my answers right?

Comment: The critical points are correct, the rest needs work - starting with your comment on translation. See link I provided and redo.

Comment: is it $X= x- 1$  and  $Y=y-e$?

Comment: but the question says not on the y-axis so i only do the (1,e)